# How to make Django The redirects app higher than urls.py?

Tags: django

Right now i'm using Django [The redirects app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/redirects/), but it has some problem.

I can't redirect from url, that have pattern in urls.py

For example i can't redirect from /arsenal1 to any page, because pattern handle it before redirect app.

```
url(r'^arsenal(?P<arsenal_id>[0-9]+)$', views.arsenal, name='arsenal'),
```

So, how can i make the high priority to The redirects app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't redirect from url, that have pattern in urls.py

Which is exactly the way it is designed to behave. See this from the doc

> The RedirectFallbackMiddleware does all of the work. Each time any
>   Django application **raises a 404 error**, this middleware checks the
>   redirects database for the requested URL as a last resort

Emphasis is mine. the redirect app is only supposed to handle urls that does not exist. Beside why would you possibly want to add an entry in urls.py and then have the redirect app override that?

I think you are probably looking for [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) which allows you to define urls in urls.py and have them redirected to various other pages (even dynamically from a database)